# Getting fatal error in Freeform CP when trying to view form submissions

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, fatal

I have a very large form with many fields that has a little over 900 submissions. The form is manually built in a template that does not use Composer. I removed some fields from the form template, and updated the notification template acccordingly. Form submission and notifications work ok, but when I try and view the submissions in the Freeform CP I get an error...

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4128 bytes) in /public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/libraries/Freeform_fields.php on line 117

I don't think this error is really due to lack of memory becasue of the size of the form, I think there's some other issue that is causing a "leak" or causing something to loop incorrectly. If it really was a memory issue, it wouldn't have popped up after making templates smaller. I removed the most recent test submissions from the DB, but that did nothing. Any idea why this is happening? Is there anything else I can check? Thanks!

Comment: Which versions of EE and Freeform are you using? What is your PHP memory limit set to?

Comment: EE v 2.7.2, Freeform Pro 4.1.3. I remember having this issue once before....

Comment: I added a bunch of new fields and got the same error. I thought I had hit some memory limits. Then I noticed my notification templates were all screwy. I had a bunch of curly quotes in my code instead of the normal quotes. I also had some fields named incorrectly in my templates, with uppercase letters where there should have been lowercase. After fixing all the quotes and fixing all the field names in the templates, the Submissions page worked in the CP fine again.

Comment: I'm not sure what fixed the issue, but one or more of those things worked. I've double checked to make sure that isn't happening again and can't find anyplace where that is the case.